# Scaling bitmap image in custom view listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have trouble with scaling and showing my bitmap images for custom view in listview items.
I usee lazyloading to show my images and while downloading and showing images my custom view show a loading gif. I customized the classes for lazyload in [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134) and it works. I think my problem is with drawing the downloaded bitmap to the canvas of my custom view.
I would like to list my problems and my code up to now.

1. The quality of images showing in custom view decreased. I dont know why.
2. When I scroll down or up my listview, it can be felt, it doesnt scroll properly.
3. My images' with should match parent and height should be scaled by the change ration of width.

Really this is a big problem for me and I can not handle it. Any help and advice would be appreciated.

getView method in my adapter

```
ImagePrevLoader imgLoader = new ImagePrevLoader(context); // actually it is initilized in constructor of adapter

public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ArtItemHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) this.context).getLayoutInflater();
        holder = new ArtItemHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.image = view.findViewById(R.id.img_Image);
        holder.pubDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_puslishDate);
        holder.arTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_arTitle);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (AdvItemHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    Article ar= articles.get(position);

    imgLoader.DisplayImage(ar.getImages().get(0).getUrl(), (ImagePreView) holder.image);    

    return view;
}

private static class ArtItemHolder{
    View image;
    TextView pubDate;
    TextView arTitle;
}
```

My Custom View

```
public class ImagePreView extends View{
    private static String TAG = "ImagePreView";
    private Movie gifImage;
    private Bitmap myImage;
    Context context;

    public ImagePreView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            new ImagePreView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }
        init();
    }
    public ImagePreView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        this.context = context;

        init();
    }
    public ImagePreView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
        this.context = context;

        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);// yada manifeste android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ekle
        //setFocusable(true);
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = context.getResources().getAssets().open("dialogbox_loader.gif");
            gifImage = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawColor(0xFFD8D8D8);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0xFFA4A4A4);
        paint.setStrokeWidth( 2.4f );
        paint.setStyle( Style.STROKE );
        canvas.drawRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint );
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(getWidth() < 1 || getHeight()<1)
            requestLayout();
        //Log.d(TAG, "WIDTH : " + getWidth()+ ", HEIGHT : " + getHeight());
        if(myImage != null){
            int width = (getWidth() - myImage.getWidth())/2;
            int height = (getHeight() - myImage.getHeight())/2;

            canvas.drawBitmap(myImage, width, height, new Paint());
        } else if(gifImage != null){
            //canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
            //Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, new Paint());
            showLoadingGif(canvas);
        }

    }

    long movieStart ;
    private void showLoadingGif(Canvas canvas){
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (movieStart == 0)
            movieStart = now;

        int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % gifImage.duration());
        gifImage.setTime(relTime);
        int width = getWidth()/2 - gifImage.width()/2;
        int height = getHeight()/2 - gifImage.height()/2;

        gifImage.draw(canvas, width, height);
        this.invalidate();
    }


    public void display(Bitmap bitmap){
        this.myImage = getScaledBitmap(bitmap);
        invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int viewWidth = getWidth();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();
        // Get current dimensions
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        int boundBoxInDp = viewWidth;
        if(viewHeight>viewWidth)
            boundBoxInDp = viewHeight;

        float xScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / width;
        float yScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / height;
        float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

        try {
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
            return scaledBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Listview item Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/feed_item_parent">

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_arTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" 
                android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
           <com.mobile.zenex.component.ImagePreView
                android:id="@+id/img_Image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_puslishDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" 
                android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Picasso for downloading/caching, it can better the quality / download speed:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: but the component on my layout it is not an imageView. it is a customview, shows a loading gif at initialization and then showing the downloded img bitmap. As I check picasso now, I could not see I can use a custom view instead of imageView. And that I think my problem is not about downloading image

Comment: I think it's because you're working directly with the Canvas object. What phone are you debugging on ?

Comment: Also, I suggest using an ASyncTask for this purpose. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. You can handle the gif showing in onPreExecute(), download the image at doInBackground and show the image at onPostExecute()

Comment: I am already using thread to download images so that it should not lock the UI. Im debugging on General Mobile 4.2.1

Comment: Wouw. I just started to use picasso. It works very good. Let me discovery it a bit. If it matchs my requirement well, İ will accept your answer